# Redirecting/redefining print() for embedded Lua

Tags: c++, c, lua

I have embedded Lua in my C++ application. I want to redirect print statements (or maybe simply redefine the print function?), so that I can display the evaluated expression somewhere else.

What is the best way to do this: redirect or redefining the print() function?

Any snippets/pointers to snippets that show how to do this would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 30):

You can redefine the print statement in C:

```
static int l_my_print(lua_State* L) {
    int nargs = lua_gettop(L);

    for (int i=1; i <= nargs; i++) {
        if (lua_isstring(L, i)) {
            /* Pop the next arg using lua_tostring(L, i) and do your print */
        }
        else {
        /* Do something with non-strings if you like */
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Then register it in the global table:

```
static const struct luaL_Reg printlib [] = {
  {"print", l_my_print},
  {NULL, NULL} /* end of array */
};

extern int luaopen_luamylib(lua_State *L)
{
  lua_getglobal(L, "_G");
  // luaL_register(L, NULL, printlib); // for Lua versions < 5.2
  luaL_setfuncs(L, printlib, 0);  // for Lua versions 5.2 or greater
  lua_pop(L, 1);
}
```

Since you are using C++ you'll need to include your file using 'extern "C"'

Comment: @MikeM. Is there a way so use this to have a call to `luaL_dostring` simply return the required output as a `char*`?

Comment: +1! exactly what I needed
@ewok, luaL_dostring returns a const char * so you have exactly what you need.

Comment: What should I return in `luaopen_luamylib()` function?

Comment: Please see my other question : https://stackoverflow.com/q/52127154/5224286

Answer (score 11):

You can simply redefine print from a Lua script.

```
local oldprint = print
print = function(...)
    oldprint("In ur print!");
    oldprint(...);
end
```

Answer (score 4):

See `luaB_print` in `lbaselib.c`. The comment there reads:

```
 /* If you need, you can define your own `print' function, following this
 model but changing `fputs' to put the strings at a proper place (a
 console window or a log file, for instance). */
```

You can just edit that function or define a new one. This has the advantage of being simple and portable, but it won't handle `io.write` (which you may or may not care about).

Redirecting IO isn't going to be platform specific (such as `SetStdHandle` in Windows), but will take care of `print` and `io.write` without redefining either.

Comment: That seems to suggest modifying the Lua sources directly (I may be wrong) - but surely, there must be a better way?

Comment: Well, I have no particular aversion to editing the Lua source, as long as I'm not changing the semantics of anything. I wrote a Lua "compiler" which bound files into the EXE as resources, then hooked Lua's file routines to read from the executable resources rather than the file system. Only had to change a few lines of source. Can't imagine what a nightmare it would have been had I tried to avoid making those changes.

Comment: The solution Mike M gives doesn't touch the Lua code. You provide a custom print function and override the default one by registering it through the Lua C function `lua_register(L,"print", my_print)`.

Answer (score 2):

Write your own C or Lua function and redefine `print`.

Answer (score 1):

You can just redefine the following macros:

```
lua_writestring
lua_writeline
lua_writestringerror
```

to whatever you like.
I'm not sure about the lua version where this was introduced - but it works in 5.3 for me.

Check your lauxlib.h or luaconf.h.

Comment: it's not enough in general, io.write() still writes to stdout.