# send lua output to non stdout

Tags: c, lua, stdout

I have a c program running embedded Lua.  as of right now, it's just a hello world.  before moving on, though, I'd like to be able to get the lua output to be sent somewhere other than `stdout`, so that I can manipulate it in some manner.  Here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include <lua.h>
#include <lauxlib.h>
#include <lualib.h>

int main() {
    lua_State *luaVM = luaL_newstate();
    //char result[1024];

    if (luaVM == NULL) {
        printf("Error initializing lua!\n");
        return -1;
    }
    luaL_openlibs(luaVM);
    luaL_dostring(luaVM, "print(\"hello world!\")");
    //Somehow put the output into result

    //printf("%s\n%s\n", result, result);

    lua_close(luaVM);
    return 0;
}
```

For example, I'd like to use `result`, seen in the comments, to print the result of the lua code twice.  Can this be done?

Comment: I've done that in the past. You will need to patch Lua to achieve this. What version are you using? My patch is for Lua 5.1, but I could port it for 5.2 as well.

Comment: I'm using 5.2.  Is this really not possible as an option in the C API?

Comment: You know, other than completely rerouting `stdout`, which I would greatly prefer to avoid

Comment: My patch was about redefining the output functions to hooks, and then setting those from application or intermediate library, so you could use your custom output functions.

Comment: @AndrejsCainikovs I don't understand.  I want to avoid rerouting `stdout` to a custom stream, as I use `stdout` for debugging purposes, and would like to avoid switching back and forth all the time.  does your patch allow me to do this?

Comment: Yes. My patch allows you to use custom output functions, specifically designed for Lua, they do not touch standard streams. Please tell me if you're interested in having them, as I'll need to do some work on this :)

Comment: @AndrejsCainikovs yes.  this patch sounds like what I need

Comment: Ok, let me bake it for you. This will take some time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This answer can get critics from some readers, but first please have a look at my [blog post](http://andrejs-cainikovs.blogspot.se/2012/08/lua-output-redirection.html) which I've prepared specially for this answer, and read the foreword why I choose this solution.

As promised, I've upstreamed my old Lua 5.1 output redirection patch to the latest version.
Patches are available here: [5.1.5](https://sites.google.com/site/andrejscainikovs/lua-5.1.5-output-redirect.patch?attredirects=0&d=1) and [5.2.1](https://sites.google.com/site/andrejscainikovs/lua-5.2.1-output-redirect.patch?attredirects=0&d=1).

**Patch**:

```
patch -p1 < ~/download/lua-5.2.1-output-redirect.patch
```

**Build**:

```
cd src  
make a LUA_A="liblua-5.2.1-redirect.a" SYSCFLAGS="-DLUA_USE_LINUX -DLUA_REDIRECT" SYSLIBS="-Wl,-E -ldl -lreadline -lncurses"
```

**Check**:

```
nm liblua-5.x.y-redirect.a | grep printf
nm liblua-5.x.y-redirect.a | grep fputs
nm liblua-5.x.y-redirect.a | grep fwrite
```

**Test**:

Obtain test program [here](https://sites.google.com/site/andrejscainikovs/lua-output-redirect-test.cpp?attredirects=0&d=1) (C/C++ mixed, sorry). Build it via:

```
g++ -DLUA_REDIRECT -I/path/to/lua-5.2.1/src/ -L. lua-redirect-test.cpp -llua-5.2.1-redirect -ldl -o lua-redirect-test
```

Output:

```
===== Test 1 output =====
Lua stdout buffer:
---
hello world!

---
Lua stderr buffer:
---

---
Lua error message:
---
(null)
---
===== Test 2 output =====
Lua stdout buffer:
---

---
Lua stderr buffer:
---

---
Lua error message:
---
[string "bad_function()"]:1: attempt to call global 'bad_function' (a nil value)
---
```

Answer (score 7):

If your Lua code is going to be using `print` to output stuff, then I guess the simplest way is to redefine `print` from Lua itself. Something like this:

```
print_stdout = print -- in case you need the old behavior

print = function(...)
  for arg,_ in ipairs({...}) do
    -- write arg to any file/stream you want here
  end
end
```

Comment: This seems like its along the lines of what I'm going for, but I need to know how to, for lack of a better term, "return" the output from `luaL_dofile()` to a `char*` in C.  can this be done this way?

Comment: What if Lua script contains syntax error? You'll need to patch Lua if you want to obtain the error in buffer rather than on stdout/stderr.

Comment: @ewok luaL_dofile() does not write to stdout. What do you mean by "output"?

Comment: @kikito, but `luaL_dostring()` seems to.  look at my code.  that code causes "hello world!" to be written to the console.  I want it in a `char*`

Comment: @ewok In that case you must redefine print from C, so that it writes to a buffer. See Mike M.'s answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4508119/redirecting-redefining-print-for-embedded-lua

Answer (score 2):

Lua's I/O library probably covers what you're looking for. The `io.output` function lets you set the default output file. Check out the [I/O library section](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#6.8) in the 5.2 manual to see what else is there.

Why do you want to reroute the output? You say you want to manipulate it in some way, but what do you mean by that?

Comment: The goal is to have the output A) displayed in a gui, rather than the console and B) with certain functions, have calculations done in C before being displayed